# Concatenation of node values based on a condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <response:performJobResponse xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <whiteboard>
            <PQ>
               <response>
                  <PQIssueHistory>
                     <AWD10SP7_1orhigher>Y</AWD10SP7_1orhigher>
                     <hostAddress>10.193.XXX.78</hostAddress>
                     <hostPort>12955</hostPort>
                     <userID>7X606</userID>
                     <password>Qfgjf@123</password>
                     <issue>
                        <CRDATTIM>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040</CRDATTIM>
                        <RECORDCD>T</RECORDCD>
                        <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                        <ORIGUSERID>DT77214</ORIGUSERID>
                     </issue>
                  </PQIssueHistory>
                  <results>
                     <row>
                        <RECTYP>HISTORY</RECTYP>
                     </row>
                     <row>
                        <date>2015-08-18</date>
                        <time>04:04:58-05:00</time>
                     </row>
                  </results>
               </response>
            </PQ>
         </whiteboard>
         <jobReturn>
            <taskName>TransformNode</taskName>
            <description>TransformNode Succeeded</description>
            <value>0</value>
         </jobReturn>
      </response:performJobResponse>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

First of all, I need to check whether any `<row>` has `<date>` and `<time>`, if so, I should concatenate the values of `<date>` and `<time>` and assign the newly generated value to a new tag `<CRDATTIM> </CRDATTIM>`.

For example: `<CRDATTIM>2015-08-18-04:04:58-05:00</CRDATTIM>`

Final resultant xml should be as below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <response:performJobResponse xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <whiteboard>
            <PQ>
               <response>
                  <PQIssueHistory>
                     <AWD10SP7_1orhigher>Y</AWD10SP7_1orhigher>
                     <hostAddress>10.193.XXX.78</hostAddress>
                     <hostPort>12955</hostPort>
                     <userID>7X606</userID>
                     <password>Qfgjf@123</password>
                     <issue>
                        <CRDATTIM>2015-07-29-04.27.15.461040</CRDATTIM>
                        <RECORDCD>T</RECORDCD>
                        <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                        <ORIGUSERID>DT77214</ORIGUSERID>
                     </issue>
                  </PQIssueHistory>
                  <results>
                     <row>
                        <RECTYP>HISTORY</RECTYP>
                     </row>
                     <row>
                        <CRDATTIM>2015-08-18-04:04:58-05:00</CRDATTIM>
                     </row>
                  </results>
               </response>
            </PQ>
         </whiteboard>
         <jobReturn>
            <taskName>TransformNode</taskName>
            <description>TransformNode Succeeded</description>
            <value>0</value>
         </jobReturn>
      </response:performJobResponse>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Having problems in verifying whether the <date> and <time> exist under  <row> or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having problems in verifying whether the `<date>` and `<time>` exist under
>   `<row>` or not.

Write a template matching the wanted rows:

```
<xsl:template match="row[date and time]">
```

and put the processing code in it.